# Lost Tezos to baker or delegator help!

Tags: transactions

I attempted to stake or delegate Tezos from atomic wallet and now I have no access to my funds, I can see them on the blockchain but how do I retrieve them, if anyone can help it has been a year and I still have no answers, please help

Comment: Are you sure you delegated and not transfer? Check on an explorer and make sure it says 'delegation' and not 'transfer'. If you transferred, you need to contact the baker and see if they are nice enough to send your funds back to you.

Comment: Thank you so much I'll check!

Comment: It says delegate but it also says received and then sent?

Comment: Can I send you the hash? Or something maybe too check it out?

Comment: Yes, post the ophash.

Comment: https://tzstats.com/tz1h2Nqx9WbgDhWbDF6JYCDMTZpV3LWag3Tz

Comment: Well, that's not the ophash. That is your address. I states quite clearly that you (or someome) transferred 34 xtz to tz1i3EmVeUTMf4YuL3fwqTa9xQWyEFodRcpG and then transferred that same 34 to another address. It's quite easy to follow the path of transfers. If you did not do this then I can only assume you got hacked and someone stole your funds.